# Android - Staggered Grid View

Tags: java, android

I followed this post to create Staggered Layout.

[No good example about RecyclerView and StaggeredGridLayoutManager in Android Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642389/no-good-example-about-recyclerview-and-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-in-android-doc)

When I am using images with different size, it works fine. But when I am using images with same size, the rows are even. It appears as ordinary grid view.

Is there any way to solve this..?

Comment: Are u trying to scale images?

Comment: Yes. Can I scale them randomly..?

Comment: Yea u make the scale range remember in float like 0.7f-1.0f and make for this random. But this is bad way becouse it can be for images same scaling number and u got ur problem. Or try to scale everythink with something like
1 image = 0.99f
2 image = 0.98f
etc.
u avoid ur problem and images will be scale for low of points from start

Comment: https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid, check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it's supposed to work:

The `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` will show a staggered grid if and only if images have different sizes: it will try to fill the gaps using a strategy that you can [define](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html#setGapStrategy(int)) in your code. There is also a [talk](https://youtu.be/gs_C1E8HwvE?t=6m44s) by Dave Smith explaining this.

If the images are all of the same size, the grid will look like a regular one.