# How to Construct a RecyclerView with Children of Variable Height?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The app I am working on contains lots of listviews. In one case, I have a recyclerView that leverages the GridLayoutManager to create a two column view. I haven't worked with recyclerViews yet as far as adapters go but here is the problem I am having. Each item in the view is being sized to the same height despite having the appropriate wrap_content attributes. I guess my question would be, is there a trick to pull this off where each child element has a different height? Is something going on behind the scenes with a recyclerView that causes all children to have a fixed height of the tallest child element? Does this sound like a recycler problem with the view holders?

My adapter logic is as follows

```
public ClubViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.onboard_club, parent, false);

    return new ClubViewHolder(itemView, mRecyclerClickListener);
}


public void onBindViewHolder(final ClubViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Item club = clubList.get(position);
    if (null != club) {
        holder.clubTitleText.setText(club.getName());
        holder.subtitleText.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.club_members,club.getNumberMembers()+""));
        // Do some imageView logic here

    }

}
```

Do I need to set height in here programmatically?

EDIT: To clarify further, the layout I inflate is the layout in question here. It is a Vertical LinearLayout containing an imageView, and two text views. I need the LinearLayout to wrap the children XML attributes but it currently isn't doing that despite the LL having a height of wrap_content and all children height set to wrap_content as well

SOLUTION: Solution was posted by a user below. I will leave the update here for anyone struggling in the future.

- Layout I need: Two columns whose children vary in height
- Tie it in with an adapter as you normally would.
- Set a StaggeredGridLayoutManager on the recyclerView widget
- In the manager constructor pass in a spanCount of 2 and an Orientation of Vertical
- Boom, close the sprint ticket and forget about it

Thanks again Stack Community, cheers!

Comment: Or you can inflate different layout by `int viewType` with different children layout

Comment: @Warrocker Why would I inflate a different layout though? They are all styled exactly the same just some of them have lines of text that wrap to a new line which pushes the content below it down so I just need the parent container to (LinearLayout in this case) to expand. I have the height of the container set to wrap content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to control placement and size of item for `RecyclerView` is through its `LayoutManager`.

If you're looking for `GridView` with elements that resize themselves according to the content you can use [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager)

Nice example of Staggered Grid Layout [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311962/2300981).

On the other hand if you need just few "groups" of different Items you can inflate different `ViewHolder`s depending on some criteria. Here is the sample code for two types of views.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == FILE_FLAG) {
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.file_item, parent, false);
        return new FileViewH(view);

    } else if (viewType == DIR_FLAG) {
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.dir_item, parent, false);
        return new DirViewH(view);

    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Worked like a charm. I used the StaggeredGridLayoutManager instead of just the GridLayoutManager. Passed in a span of 2 and an orientation of vertical. I will update my post with the solution.

Comment: You're welcome. If you like to expand my answer it would be more in Q&A website paradigm to answer your question with the new answer in contrast to updating the question itself with an answer...