# Grid view with show more option

Tags: android, gridview

I want to implement a grid view with show more option. I have 16 pre-defined categories. I want to show only first row of grid view with more option at the end. User can see all 16 items by clicking more button like drop down menu.

I'm trying to find some library but noting work for me.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

We suggest, please use the staggered grid with recycler view which is same like grid view also some extra benefits like, In this, you are using recycler view so its good another one you can span how you want also you can enlarge how you want, Bellow is some link which helps you.

[No good example about RecyclerView and StaggeredGridLayoutManager in Android Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642389/no-good-example-about-recyclerview-and-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-in-android-doc)

https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html

https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-recyclerview.html