# Android CardView with StaggeredLayout

Tags: android, android-cardview, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I am kinda new to Android and I am experimenting with different layouts and so on. Today, I was creating RecyclerView with CardViews as items. All great, but I also found staggered layout manager. So I created RecyclerView with staggered view, and images, etc. Next step, I wanted to create CardView and the contents of this CardView are images that are in "staggered view like". Like on this image

[image: CardView staggered layout manager]

Any idea how to implement this? I would be happy with any pointers.

Regards,
golobich

Comment: Possible duplicate, have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311962/1381007

Comment: @abhie yes. Question is not how to create recycler view with staggered view, but how to create cardview that has staggered layout. In recycler view, I see that you can say setLayoutManager and pass the staggeredLayoutManager, but cardView does not have anything like this