# How to Make StageredRecyclerView?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

how to make Stagered RecyclerView? so that the columns stand randomly, i'm Beginner and so much tutorial stageredrecyclerview by java, about Kotlin tutorial how to make randomly stageredRecyclerView unfortunatly I haven't found , can someone bring simple please. thank advance

this is my code (column and Stagered Manager I already wrote in xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#F4F4F4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_recycler"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>






class AgroMarktFragment: Fragment(), IntFaceClickRecycler {

    var binding : AgromarktLayoutBinding? = null

    private val vm by viewModel<AgroMarkViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding =  AgromarktLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding?.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        hereWeGo()


    }

    private fun hereWeGo() {
        val adapter = AgroAdapter(this)

        binding?.RecyclerView?.adapter = adapter
        vm.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.update(it)
        })
    }

    override fun gotoTheDetails(data: Dataclass) {
        val dest = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToDetailsFragment(data)
        findNavController().navigate(dest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources on StaggeredGridLayout recyclerview implementation are scarce.

Lucky for you here is the example thread on stackoverflow, a solution for simple implementation of staggered grid.

[No good example about RecyclerView and StaggeredGridLayoutManager in Android Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642389/no-good-example-about-recyclerview-and-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-in-android-doc)

Comment: sadly there on java, I don't know Java